# Write macro to create match arms

Tags: rust, macros

I am creating a histogram based on an array of integers. The code below works fine but looks terrible because I had to write so many match arms by hand. But it feels like there should be a better way to do this, and I assume that way is a macro. Could you point me in the right direction?

```rust
pub fn make_histogram(array: &[u64]) {
    let mut counts = HashMap::new();
    for value in array.iter() {
        match value {
            1..=2000 => *counts.entry("1-2000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            2001..=4000 => *counts.entry("2001-4000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            4001..=6000 => *counts.entry("4001-6000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            6001..=8000 => *counts.entry("6001-8000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            8001..=10000 => *counts.entry("8001-10000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            10001..=12000 => *counts.entry("10001-12000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            12001..=14000 => *counts.entry("12001-14000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            14001..=16000 => *counts.entry("14001-16000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            16001..=18000 => *counts.entry("16001-18000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            18001..=20000 => *counts.entry("18001-20000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            20001..=22000 => *counts.entry("20001-22000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            22001..=24000 => *counts.entry("22001-24000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            24001..=26000 => *counts.entry("24001-26000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            26001..=28000 => *counts.entry("26001-28000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            28001..=30000 => *counts.entry("28001-30000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            30001..=32000 => *counts.entry("30001-32000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            32001..=34000 => *counts.entry("32001-34000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            34001..=36000 => *counts.entry("34001-36000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            36001..=38000 => *counts.entry("36001-38000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            38001..=40000 => *counts.entry("38001-40000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            40001..=42000 => *counts.entry("40001-42000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            42001..=44000 => *counts.entry("42001-44000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            44001..=46000 => *counts.entry("44001-46000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            46001..=48000 => *counts.entry("46001-48000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            48001..=50000 => *counts.entry("48001-50000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            50001..=52000 => *counts.entry("50001-52000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            52001..=54000 => *counts.entry("52001-54000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            54001..=56000 => *counts.entry("54001-56000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            56001..=58000 => *counts.entry("56001-58000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            58001..=60000 => *counts.entry("58001-60000").or_insert(0) += 1,
            _ => *counts.entry("60001-inf").or_insert(0) += 1,
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need a [proc macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) to significantly improve your situation, but you can get a long way by moving the common bits `*counts.entry(` and `).or_insert(0) += 1` outside of the `match`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Despite the title, your question suggests you are looking for a solution to your problem that doesn't necessarily need to involve a `HashMap` or match arms.*

If performance is important for you, I would rather consider using an array, instead of a `HashMap`. It seems like your step is fixed, so you could just write something like this:

```
use std::cmp;

const STEP_SIZE: u64 = 2_000;
const STEPS_COUNT: usize = 30;

// ...
let mut counts = [0; STEPS_COUNT];
// ...
for value in array {
    let idx = cmp::min(((value - 1) / STEP_SIZE) as usize, STEPS_COUNT-1);
    counts[idx] += 1;
}
```

The range-strings that you're using in your `HashMap` as keys look like something you could construct where needed. You could do that every time (on the fly), or you could generate the strings once and cache them (for example in an array of `String`s).